# How to get the entry assembly reference in ASP NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a library that is shared across several applications and I am looking for a way to get the assembly version of the startup project from inside this shared library.

Is there a way to get this data in this shared library without passing this data into it directly?

The applications are:

- WinForms
- ASP.NET site
- ASP.NET web service

**Update:**

The .Net framework version is 4.5.2.

Have tried using `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version`, but got an exception generated in the shared library generated when calling `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version`.

Exception:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
```

Comment: What framework does your shared library target? I normally use Assembly.GetEntryAssembly, but that's not public in early versions of .NET Standard.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thank you for the advice, but using Assembly.GetEntryAssembly did solve my problem. Have updated my question with some details.

Comment: So have you worked out which part of that expression was null? It could be that `GetEntryAssembly()` returns null, or that `Assembly.GetName()` returns null, potentially.